# Does ffmpeg supported KLV metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

Is ffmpeg metadata, which is also described in:
http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_Metadata
also supported MISB standard UAV metadata 601.5 ?
Is it same as KLV   ?

Thanks,
Ran

Answer (score 21, accepted):

FFMPEG does not natively support MISB KLV metadata or have demuxers or decoders for KLV metadata of these types at this time.

However, FFMPEG can be used to extract data elementary streams from containers like MPEG Transport Stream (TS) per ISO 13818-1. Such capability works for UDP streams and local MPEG TS Files. See the examples at end of response. The examples simply extract the data from the stream, they do not parse them. Parsing could easily be accomplished in real time by piping the output or post processing using many languages including C and Python.

It would be helpful to know specifically which containers you are trying to extract data from. In lieu of such information I have assumed MPEG TS in my response and examples. I would like to also point out that the current standard for ["UAS Local Dataset" is now ST0601.8](http://www.gwg.nga.mil/misb/docs/standards/ST0601.8.pdf) at the time of this response.

I have personally tested the following examples with FFMPEG 2.5.4 on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

The following examples can be modified such that the output is sent to stdout by replacing the `<outfile>` with '-'.

Extract Data Stream From MPEG-TS File at Line Speed and Save to Binary File:

```
ffmpeg -i <MPEGTS_infile> -map d -codec copy -f data <binary_outfile>
```

Extract Data Stream From MPEG-TS File at Frame Rate and Save to Binary File:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <MPEGTS_infile> -map d -codec copy -f data <binary_outfile>
```

Extract Data Stream From MPEG-TS UDP Stream at Stream Rate and Save to Binary File:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://@<address:port> -map d -codec copy -f data <binary_outfile>
```

Extract Data Stream From MPEG-TS UDP Stream at Stream Rate and Direct to STDOUT:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://@<address:port> -map d -codec copy -f data -
```

Stream Video, Audio and Data Streams from MPEG-TS file Over UDP at Frame Rate:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <MPEGTS_infile> -map 0 -c copy -f mpegts udp://<address:port>
```

Comment: I faced this problem a number of years ago and implemented a python parser, see [https://github.com/paretech/klvcms](https://github.com/paretech/klvcms). The parser is flexible, extensible but incomplete. It's more of an API, but can easily print the data to a text file or pass to the next processing item in line. Alternatively, depending on your needs (and possibly your affiliations), a program like [PAR GV](http://www.gv30.net/) might better address your needs.

Comment: @paretech, Thanks for the great answer. You mentioned piping the `stdout` to a python script. My question is, what data structure is best suited to holding 3000kb+ of binary klv data as it is being read from and written to at the same time? Would a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html) be good for this?

Comment: @VictorOdouard, I'm not sure that I fully understand the question or at least understand some of its complexities. To help get you the answer you need, can you please open a new question and distill the problem down to the essence? 

On the other hand, if you are asking how to operate on live data streams for a long period of time, I can tell you that I have piped output from FFMPEG to the mentioned python script and let the program run for weeks if not months on end. When doing so I took no special measures and let the OS and Python do its thing.

Comment: You can decode it with directshow filter  https://github.com/EliArad/KLVDecoder

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure if UAV metadata 601.5 is the same as KLV, but FFmpeg can demux KLV metadata since commit 69a042e from 28 Oct 2013:

- [mpegts: demux synchronous SMPTE 336M Key-Length-Value (KLV) metadata](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=69a042ee95c60d429f6dd6473caa1a88381a4da2)

This fixes ticket #2579: [Data stream from UAV video reported as "Unknown" type and without codec_id set](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2579), so you may find other relevant information there too.

Comment: ffmpeg is said to support KLV in MXF files , https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/mxfdec_8c-source.html, 
I wander if I can validate that ffmpeg can retrieve KLV information from MXF by using ffplay. What do you think ?