# Embedding SMPTE 336M KLV data into video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts

I have a drone video in .MP4 format, and an accompanying log file containing various timecoded data, e.g. GPS location, altitude.

I need to embed the data into the video in the SMPTE 336M (KLV Data Encoding Protocol Using Key-Length-Value) standard format.

I've successfully extracted KLV data from a MPEG2-TS file using FFMPEG and a parser in Node.

Now I need to go the other way: to generate KLV data from my log file and insert it into the relevant video. How this is done?

Comment: A quick search leads me to believe this task is supported by ffmpeg: https://github.com/rvs/ffmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mxfenc.c

Comment: This sounds just like a bad idea as you need not only to develop or "control" the encoder but also the decoder. Are you sure your usecase is valid and you are looking into the right technology? ..nobody can decode the data besides a player that you developed...

Comment: Harry - was your comment to me, or to the preceding comment? I want to take a video and a log file containing location data, and combine them into a single file in the standard SMPTE 336M standard. If done correctly, why should this mean that "nobody can decode the data besides the player you developed"?

Comment: @Mateo I'm interested to know how you extracted the KLV data with ffmpeg. Can you post more details please?

Comment: @AwayTeam sorry I missed your comment. I forget the exact details, but I believe I began with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29461404/671114

Comment: Which node parser did you use please? @Mateo

Comment: I'm working on that. I have how to generate the klv but I don't know how to insert it into the video and all the attempts have failed. Here you have the code https://github.com/All4Gis/QGISFMV/blob/master/code/manager/QgsMultiplexor.py

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is 6 years old, but you can do it with just ffmpeg and node, which you said you're already using.

Here is how:

1. Make sure you have downloaded ffmpeg and ffprobe.
2. Add the npm fluent-ffmpeg to your current folder.
3. Create this in a JS file and and alter to your KLV needs.
4. Execute it. It will create a new mp4 file with your KLV data!

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('/path/to/ffmpeg.exe')
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath('/path/to/ffprobe.exe')

function addKlvData(videoPath, key, value, outputPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ffmpeg(videoPath)
        .outputOptions('-metadata', `${key}=${value}`) // Separate option and value strings
        .output(outputPath)
        .on('error', (err) => {
          console.error(`ffmpeg error: ${err.message}`);
          reject(err);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          console.log('ffmpeg processing completed, metadata added');
          resolve();
        })
        .run();
    });
  }
  
  // Example usage
  addKlvData('yourInput.mp4', 'yourKey', 'Your KLV data', 'output-with-metadata.mp4')
    .then(() => console.log('Metadata added successfully'))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

To make sure your metadata was added, just use ffprobe, like this...

```
ffprobe -i output-with-metadata.mp4 -show_format
```

...you'll see something like this...

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output-with-metadata.mp4':
  Metadata:
    yourKeyHere     : Your metadata here
```